# Discord.js deleteMessage() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I am creating a Discord bot with discord.js and I'd like to create a command that can clear messages. For now, I have this code (only the interesting part) and I can't figure out why it doesn't work:

```
// Importing discord.js, creating bot and setting the prefix 
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = "/";

// Array that stores all messages sent
messages = [];

bot.on('message', (message) => {

   // Store the new message in the messages array
   messages.push(message);

   // Split the command so that "/clear all" becames args["clear", "all"]
   var args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

   // If the command is "/clear all"
   if(args[0] == "clear" && args[1] == "all") {

      bot.deleteMessages(messages); // Code that doesn't work

      // Resets the array
      messages = [];

   }
}

// CONNECT !!!
bot.login('LOGING TOKEN HERE');
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Please create the smallest possible code that demonstrates your problem, then post that. The code you've posted now does not even have balanced braces, so I cannot tell if you have any syntax errors that are causing problems.

Comment: Ok I've fixed it @wmorrell !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`<TextChannel>.bulkDelete`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) instead.

Example:

```
msg.channel.bulkDelete(100).then(() => {
    msg.channel.send("Purged 100 messages.").then(m => m.delete(3000));
});
```

This would delete `2 - 100` messages in a channel for every call to this method so you would not receive `429 (Too many Requests) Error` frequently which might result in your [token being revoked](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/reference#rate-limiting).

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. the `messages` array is always empty; there is no code that adds items to the array, so the call to `bot.deleteMessages` will always get an empty array;
2. it does not appear that `deleteMessages` is an available method on [`Discord.Client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client);

Based on the documentation, I think what you want is `sweepMessages`. The description of that states:

> Sweeps all text-based channels' messages and removes the ones older than the max message lifetime. If the message has been edited, the time of the edit is used rather than the time of the original message.

Try changing the code to instead call `bot.sweepMessages(1);`, which I think will tell the client to clear all messages older than one second.

Comment: Sorry I have too minified my code, in mine, it appends the `messages` array when someone writes a message.
Also, `sweepMessages()` is recognized but it seems that it does nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this, without `sweepMessages` is by using `fetchMessages`:

```
let user = message.mentions.users.first();
let amount = !!parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[1]) ? parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[1]) : parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[2])
var prefix = '!'


if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'clear') && !amount) 
    return message.reply('Must specify an amount to clear!');
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'clear') && !amount && !user) return message.reply('Must specify a user and amount, or just an amount, of messages to clear!');
    message.channel.fetchMessages({
        limit: amount,
    }).then((messages) => {
    if (user) {
        const filterBy = user ? user.id : bot.user.id;
        messages = messages.filter(m => m.author.id === filterBy).array().slice(0, amount);
    }
    message.channel.bulkDelete(messages).catch(error => console.log(error.stack));
});
```

This will allow users to use the command `!clear [#]` to delete that number of messages when sent. If it is run as just `!clear` you can set how many get deleted, without a specified number.

[discord.js Documentation - TextChannel#fetchMessages](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages)

Answer (score 0):

You can swap

```
bot.deleteMessages()
```

to:

```
messages.forEach(x => x.delete())
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not like that. you should fetch the messages first then use `bulkDelete` to delete them
, here is a simple example

```js
// Normal Javascript
<Message>.channel.fetchMessages()
.then(messages => {
// Here you can use bulkDelete(101) to delete 100 messages instead of using fetchMessages and deleting only 50
<Message>.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
});
// ES6
let messages = await <Message>.channel.fetchMessages();
// Here you can use bulkDelete(101) to delete 100 messages instead of using fetchMessages and deleting only 50
await <Message>.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
```